Dynamically generate variable group names in Azure Pipelines
I want to dynamically generate a variable group name on Azure pipelines, based on a variable that is coming from a variable group. I found several questions related to this, but none seems to address this specific use case.
So far, this has been working for us with the following code:
variables:
  - group: release

jobs:
- job: blue
  condition: eq(variables['deployment'], 'blue')
  variables:
  - group: blue-vars
  steps:
    - template: ../templates/some-code.yml

- job: green
  condition: eq(variables['deployment'], 'green')
  variables:
  - group: green-vars
  steps:
    - template: ../templates/some-code.yml

But now we need to extend this implementation, and we will have 10-12 jobs from whose only one will execute, according to the $(deployment) variable (coming from the release variable group). That is ugly, and difficult to maintain if we will need 10-12 blocks doing the exact same, with the same variables having different values, so I would like to refactor this solution.
I tried the obvious solution (below), but it doesn't work most likely because the $(deployment) variable is only available on runtime, and needs to be available on compilation time.
- job: a_single_colour_1
  variables:
  - group: $(deployment)-vars
  steps:
    - template: ../templates/some-code.yml

I tried with compile-time expressions, but it seems that variables coming from variable groups are not resolved before compiling the expressions, so the below attempt is also failing:
- job: a_single_colour_2
  variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['deployment'], 'blue') }}:
    - group: blue-vars
  - ${{ if eq(variables['deployment'], 'green') }}:
    - group: green-vars
  steps:
    - template: ../templates/some-code.yml

After going through the documentation, I decided to use runtime expressions - as shown below - but it fails due to an error in the YAML (seems not to be supported):
 job: a_single_colour_3
  variables:
  - $[ if eq(variables['deployment'], 'blue') ]:
    - group: blue-vars
  - $[ if eq(variables['deployment'], 'green') ]:
    - group: green-vars
  steps:
    - template: ../templates/some-code.yml

Lastly, I tried to use a job template (code below), and I can see clearly that the variable $(deployment) is also not being resolved, causing a compile-time error due to the incompatible value for the deployment parameter.
On the main pipeline
- template: job_template.yml
  parameters: 
    deployment: $(deployment)

job_template.yml
parameters:
- name: deployment
  type: string
  values:
  - green
  - blue

jobs:
- job: a_single_colour_4
  variables:
  - name: deployment
    value: ${{ parameters.deployment }}
  - ${{ if eq(variables['deployment'], 'blue') }}:
    - group: blue-vars
  - ${{ if eq(variables['deployment'], 'green') }}:
    - group: green-vars
  steps:
    - template: ../templates/some-code.yml

Any idea how can I achieve what I want?

The condition expands at runtime time so it is working, but if expression is expanded at compile time. If you don't want to use condition, consider below two workarounds in the reply.


I want to dynamically generate a variable group name on Azure pipelines, based on a variable that is coming from a variable group

My first suggestion would be to redesign your pipeline to avoid this situation, e.g. maybe using a pipeline parameter instead of the first variable group (release)?
In case that's not possible, and in order to reduce code duplication, you can use a loop to generate all possible jobs and use conditions to define which one will execute, according to the value of $(deployment).
Example:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
  - name: colors
    displayName: 'All possible values for the colors'
    type: object
    default:
      - green
      - blue

variables:
  - group: release

jobs:
  - ${{ each color in parameters.colors }}:
    - job: ${{ color }}
      condition: eq(variables['deployment'], '${{ color }}')
      variables:
      - group: ${{ color }}-vars
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - script: echo "Hello, $(color)!"
          displayName: 'Display color from variable group'

Running the job when $(deployment) is set to green:


The redesign you suggest isn't possible in this scenario. This variable group is used by multiple pipelines, and shouldn't be hardcoded as a parameter.
But the solution you proposed is smart and does address my problem!

@ccoutinho if my answer helped please consider accepting it. Thanks!

It's not supported to directly determine the variable group by the variable in another variable group in same pipeline.
As per the doc, to reference a variable in a variable group, you need to use macro syntax or a runtime expression, which is after compile time. However, both if expression and group definition in yaml are expanded at compile time.
The approach by @Rui Jarimba is actually using parameter value instead of variable for the variable group name. Need to specify all possible values in parameters and loop to find the match value.
Another work around is, you can use two pipelines, get the target variable group name in 1st pipeline, and transfer it as parameter to 2nd real pipeline, the parameter can be used as variable group name.
The 1st pipeline sample:
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

variables:
 - group: release

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $body = '
      { 
              "definition": {
                  "id": 619
              },
              "templateParameters": {
                "vgname": "$(deployment)-vars"
             }
      }
      '
      $personalToken = "$(personalToken)"
      $token =   [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
      $header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
      $Uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7"
      Write-Host $Uri
      $buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $Uri -Body $body -Headers $header
      write-host $buildresponse

The 2nd pipeline(your real one):
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters: 
  - name: vgname
    type: string


variables:
   - group: ${{ parameters.vgname }}

steps:
- script: |
    echo $(color)   # echo $(color) from 2nd variable group for testing
  displayName: 'Check value'

The variable $(color) in target variable group is exported:

You can use system.accesstoken instead of PAT if needed. Please check the my answer in simialr ticket.
